# How can I clear a Windows 7 console screen between function calls in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have tried system calls to cls as well as the following code:

```
function clear() {
     process.stdout.write('\u001B[2J\u001B[0;0f');
}
```

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

One windows you should be able to do:

```
var util = require('util');
util.print("\u001b[2J\u001b[0;0H");
```

Comment: Sorry, I just tried & it didn't work. I should tell you that I am running the script in cmd.exe as such: node script.js

Comment: Hmm, then you could fake it I guess, something like `for(var i = 0; i < process.stdout.getWindowSize()[1]; i++) { console.log('\r\n'); }`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the escape sequence as given [here](http://www.computerhope.com/ansisys.htm#06). The escape sequence for clearing the screen is `ESC[2J`, which translates to outputting `'\033[2J'`.

I tried and it worked for me on windows

Comment: Alas, this did not work for me either, In fact, it won't work at all with strict enabled. Even by disabling strict, it still does nothing.